# When using PHP code to build a DIF structure on my main page, it seems to not pick up the styling set up in my CSS file

Tags: php, html, css

I have updated my code and need help with new problem.

I have a grid set up on my main page:inside the blue box. Now, you can hover over any of the items in the grid and a message pops up showing info from my database. This currently works.
When the user selects one of the 5 round targets, the system deletes the current grid contents and then calls a PHP program to re-populate the grid with a new set of items.
Currently, the original contents are removed ok, and a new set of pictures are put in the grid. This works as well.
However, now when you hover over the new item, it does not trigger the popup showing the info.

To see the problem in real time, visit magic.richtemen.com

Here is my HTML setup.

```
<div class="grid-container" id="gridbox">
    <div class="grid-item">
        <img class="hover" id="1" src="https://c1.scryfall.com/file/scryfall-cards/small/front/7/0/7050735c-b232-47a6-a342-01795bfd0d46.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the call to delete the grid's contents.

document.getElementById(elementID).innerHTML = "";

This works.

Here is the PHP Code to re-populate the grid contents.

```
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo "<div class='grid-item'>";
            echo "<img class='hover' id='1' src={$row['cPictURL']} />";
            echo "<p style='color:black;font-size:small'>{$row['cName']} 
   </p>";
            echo "</div>";
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I entered in your website and saw your code. Try to remove `<br />` from your php code!

Comment: This fixed the problem of the layout of the items in the grid. However, now these new items will no longer respond to the 'hover' function.  Is there some function to re-enable the class on these new items?

Comment: @rtemen probably because some css class is missing. Check your code for your classes to see if they match